# Permutations of $10$ people with $3$ people together

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can $10$ people stand in a row such that $3$ of them are always together?

I got it as $7!$ ways because three people are together. Then those three can be put in $3!$ ways. So, the answer I got is $7!3!$ ways. But the answer is $241920$, which sure is not $7!3!$.

Comment: You could also do this by counting the ways to choose the places for the 3 people, multiply by the number of ways to arrange them in these 3 places, and then multiply by the number of ways to arrange the other 7 people in their spots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to include the group of the $3$ people while permuting. This group will be in addition to the other $7$ members which gives $8!$ ways. The total would then be $8!3! = 241920$ ways.

Comment: oops.. right! So, the group should be treated as a single individual?

Comment: @AndyRock yes, you are right!